# Flutter (Unable to load asset)

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I'm unable to load images to my app although I tried many solutions
my code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[900],
          title: const Text("hi"),
        ),
        
        body:   Image(image: AssetImage("images/ab.png"),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my pubspec.yaml

[image]

flutter doctor

[image]

1- I used $ flutter clean and then $ flutter pub get.

2- I updated flutter SDK.

3- I mention only the folder (images).

4- I used a smaller image.

5- I restarted my laptop.

6- I run my code in another IDE.

but nothing is working for me, so can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your project folder structure?

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your `main.dart` code, I created a `images` folder with a `.png` file.

I think the problem could be the position of the `images` folder, you should place it beside the `lib` folder.

Without seeing the project folder structure I cannot be sure, but if you do it like that your code should work fine.

[image]

Here's the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:

  assets:
    - images/
```

Here's a screenshot of the your code running:

[image]

Comment: I deleted the project and rewritten it then it work fine